# Is it possible to get the output of ioreg in a more easily parse-able format?

Tags: macos

I need to get the output of `ioreg` in Mac OS X for further processing, however the tree like structure it uses is difficult to parse? Is there any way to get the output in XML or something easier to parse (like `system_profiler`)?

```
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, retain 12>
  | {
  |   ...
  | }
  | 
  +-o MacBookPro5,1  <class IOPlatformExpertDevice, registered, matched, active, busy 0, retain 25>
    | {
    |   ...
    | }
    | 
    +-o AppleACPIPlatformExpert  <class AppleACPIPlatformExpert, registered, matched, active, busy 0, retain 51>
    | | {
    | |   ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A long road can be to grab the source code to ioreg and modify it...

https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitTools/IOKitTools-108/ioreg.tproj/

Download:

- [ioreg.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitTools/IOKitTools-108/ioreg.tproj/ioreg.c)
- [IOKitLibPrivate.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1445.40.1/IOKitLibPrivate.h)
- [IOKitKeysPrivate.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/iokit/IOKit/IOKitKeysPrivate.h)

Change the `#include <IOKit/IOKitLibPrivate.h>` and `#include <IOKit/IOKitKeysPrivate.h >` to `#include "IOKitLibPrivate.h"` and `#include "IOKitKeysPrivate.h"` so you can compile when both files is in same directory, then compile with

```
cc -o ioreg ioreg.c -framework Foundation -framework IOKit -lcurses
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `ioreg` man page one can use the `-a` flag to generate output in `XML`.

If you're using python, you can simply create a plist element tree with:

```py
import plistlib
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["ioreg", "-alw0", "-p", "IOUSB"])
pl = plistlib.loads(output, fmt=plistlib.FMT_XML)
```

After that you can filter it or manipulate it in the desired way.