# How do I iterate through IO Kit's keys?

Tags: c++, c, macos

I am trying to get a list of all devices in the system together with how they are connected. Therefore, I want to essentially clone the structure of the IO Kit services tree (that you can see with `IORegistryExplorer`). How do I iterate through all the keys? (One of the reasons this is confusing to me is because I dont understand what the difference between `io_service`, `io_registry`, and `io_object` are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between service, registry and object is only in the circumstances they are used. Otherwise they are *completely the same*.
From IOTypes.h:

```
typedef io_object_t io_registry_entry_t;
typedef io_object_t io_service_t;
```

There is documentation available about [Traversing the I/O Registry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_IOKitLib_API/AH_IOKitLib_API.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000380-TPXREF112), which also includes information on traversing the whole registry.
For each entry you then would have to [get the properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_IOKitLib_API/AH_IOKitLib_API.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000380-BABIDJDI) and save them with your representation of the registry.

So you would use `IORegistryGetRootEntry()`, print/save its name and properties and then iterate over the children with [`IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOKitLib_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator).

You get the properties with `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties()` following a[`CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues). For the values you then have to check what types these are to print/save them (or use CFSHOW). When you really want to clone this into a different structure (with different types) you have to handle every possible CFTypeID explicitely.

I created a working prototype at
https://gist.github.com/JonnyJD/6126680

---

EDIT:

In [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/587708/1904815) the (C) source code of `ioreg` is linked. That should be a good resource for printing/extracting missing CFTypes.